# code igniter auth(Tank Auth) logs me out for no reason (i.e. overloaded may be)

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter, apache2, tankauth

i have a controller and a view indicated as below which works perfect for some time, but after some requests are made to the server(i.e. keeps reloading every one second) it will fail on this line

```
 if (!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in())
```

for no reason, i don't know weather it is congested or ...

when i try to debug the client code in firebug and hold a put a break point on this line

```
  $('#buy_reload').load('buy/reload'); //And press f8 every time
```

it woks like charm what is the problem? load?

Z controller

```
class Buy extends CI_Controller
{
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('tank_auth');
    $this->load->model(array('tank_auth/users','players','cash','inventory','items','shopping_cart','purchases','processing'));
}

function reload()
{
    if (!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) { 
        redirect('/auth/login/');
    } else {
            //do those stuffs
           }

}
}
```

a script inside Z view

```
  <script>
   setInterval(function() {
   $('#buy_reload').load('buy/reload');
   }, 1 * 1000);
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with Tank Auth and CodeIgniter 2.1 .
There seems to be an issue with sessions and Ajax calls.
The following links will help you

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/199753/#962141

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/203821/#951378

The problem is in the sess_update function of the session class, that generates a new session_id after X seconds. Every page have a session_id, if the session_id expires before the ajax call is made, that call will fail.

Comment: it is not exactly with the ajax calls only as i see but your links provided the answer and explanation of the problem here http://www.hiretheworld.com/blog/tech-blog/codeigniter-session-race-conditions Thanks